# Running Redshift script as a service

Tags: scripts, 20.04, services, redshift

I am very new to Linux and I am trying to get practice writing scripts and making my own services. I wanted to take my simple simple redshift script that changes the color temp of my screen and make it a service. The script works when I execute it in the terminal, but when I try to execute it in a .service file I run into issue. Any help would be appreciated.

**My Script (redshift.sh):**

```
#!/bin/bash
redshift -O 1500
```

by running `./redshift.sh` I see my screen change color temp and get output: `Using method randr`.

**My Service (redshift.service):**

```
[Unit]
Description=Set Redshift
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/redshift.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Expectation is to have *redshift.service* execute my script *redshift.sh*.

**Setting up Service:**

I copyed the script file to `/usr/bin` and changed mode to x (executable).

```
sudo cp redshift.sh /usr/bin/redshift.sh 
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/redshift.sh
```

I copied the service file to `/etc/systemd/system` and changed mode to 644.

```
sudo cp redshift.service /etc/systemd/system/redshift.service 
sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/redshift.service
```

**Trying to run my service:**

```
sudo systemctl start redshift
```

Display color temp does not change!

**Getting Status of Service:**

```
sudo systemctl status redshift
```

Judging by the output of systemctl status, I see that the script tried to execute, but some failures occurred. Any thoughts on why this might be the case? Status output is shown below.

```
"Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redshift.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-09-04 11:40:11 EDT; 8s ago
    Process: 21928 ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/redshift.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 21928 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p bash[21933]: `RANDR Query Version' returned error -1
Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p bash[21933]: Initialization of randr failed.
Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p bash[21933]: Trying next method...
Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p bash[21933]: No protocol specified
Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p bash[21933]: X request failed: XOpenDisplay
Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p bash[21933]: Initialization of vidmode failed.
Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p bash[21933]: Trying next method...
Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p bash[21933]: No more methods to try.
Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p systemd[1]: redshift.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FA>
Sep 04 11:40:11 labpc-ThinkPad-T540p systemd[1]: redshift.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'."
```

[image: status output]

I was following this tutorial to make my service: https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/start-service-at-boot/#create-a-custom-systemd-service

Answer (score 1):

You might have to set env variables such as display & Xauth.

My service has this line added to the `[service]` section

```
Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority"
```

See this [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177473) for further detail.

Also the execstart does not have to be a .sh. You can set the path to be the redshift exec (or in your case type the command as you would in a terminal as I guess redshift is in your PATH)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define display as environment and run after display manager starts.

Please see content below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Redshift
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redshift -O 1500
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

You can also define parameters in `ExeStart` and eliminate extra custom bash script.